# How do you turn the text in the html into a equation using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a simple rpg game using jquery and am having issues with turning an string into a number that JS can run a equation from. So I have click events on each character so when the user chooses one, it changes the html to that characters stats in a spans. I would like to take those numbers and use them for my attack button.

I also would like to increase the damage of the main character each time the button is clicked by 4.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-3 "><button id="atk">Attack!</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class=" col-md-2 ">Health: <span id="Hp"></span></p>
        <p class=" col-md-2 ">Damage Output: <span id="Damage"></span></p>
        <p class=" col-md-2 ">Enemy Health: <span id="eHp"></span></p>
        <p class=" col-md-2 ">Enemy Damage Output: <span id="eDamage"></span></p>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#atk").click(function(){
   foeHp= ($("#eHp").html());
   foeDmg= ($("#eDamage").html());
   mainHp= ($("#Hp").html());
   mainDmg= ($("#Damage").html());
// console.log(foeDmg);


var enemyHp = eval(foeHp + (mainDmg -4));
```

Comment: `eval` seems entirely unwarranted here. Why are you using it? If you need to turn a string into a number, use `parseInt`.

Comment: Use the `Number()` function, the unary plus operator, `parseFloat()`, or `parseInt()` on the individual values, and then you can do whatever mathematical operations you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `eval`, you're looking for **[`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)** or [**`parseInt()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). You'd be better off parsing the variables themselves as integers, so you don't have to worry about doing so for **every** calculation:

```js
$("#atk").click(function() {
  foeHp = parseInt($("#eHp").html());
  foeDmg = parseInt($("#eDamage").html());
  mainHp = parseInt($("#Hp").html());
  mainDmg = parseInt($("#Damage").html());
  var enemyHp = foeHp + (mainDmg - 4);
  console.log("You did " + mainDmg + " damage.");
  console.log("The enemy now has " + enemyHp + " HP.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button id="atk">Attack!</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <p class="col-md-2">Health: <span id="Hp">7</span></p>
  <p class="col-md-2">Damage Output: <span id="Damage">2</span></p>
  <p class="col-md-2">Enemy Health: <span id="eHp">3</span></p>
  <p class="col-md-2">Enemy Damage Output: <span id="eDamage">4</span></p>
</div>
```

**Never** use `eval()`, as it can lead to serious security vulnerabilities. Remember, **[`eval` is 'evil'](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)**!

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It does! Thank you!!

Comment: Just did that! One more thing if you can help me out one last time. How do I set it up so every time I click the button it adds 4 to the damage output. I can get it to add 4 once but not each time the click event activates.

Comment: Thanks, and that's easy enough. Just make use of another variable, let's say `bonusDmg`. Define that **outside** of the click event: `var bonusDmg`. Then **inside** the click event, increment it by 4: `bonusDmg = bonusDmg + 4` (or alternatively `bonusDmg += 4`). Then you can use that as a 'fluid' value inside your mathematical equation: `enemyHp = foeHp + (mainDmg - bonusDmg)` :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again. I'm new to jQuery so I appreciate it!